# Interesting Scala typing solution, doesn't work in 2.7.7?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to build some image algebra code that can work with images (basically a linear pixel buffer + dimensions) that have different types for the pixel. To get this to work, I've defined a parametrized Pixel trait with a few methods that should be able to get used with any Pixel subclass. (For now, I'm only interested in operations that work on the same Pixel type.) Here it is:

```
trait Pixel[T <: Pixel[T]] {
    def div(v: Double): T
    def div(v: T): T
}
```

Now I define a single Pixel type that has storage based on three doubles (basically RGB 0.0-1.0), I've called it TripleDoublePixel:

```
class TripleDoublePixel(v: Array[Double]) extends Pixel[TripleDoublePixel] {

    var data: Array[Double] = v

    def this() = this(Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    def div(v: Double): TripleDoublePixel = {
        new TripleDoublePixel(data.map(x => x / v))
    }

    def div(v: TripleDoublePixel): TripleDoublePixel = {
        var tmp = new Array[Double](3)
        tmp(0) = data(0) / v.data(0)
        tmp(1) = data(1) / v.data(1)
        tmp(2) = data(2) / v.data(2)
        new TripleDoublePixel(tmp)
    }

}
```

Then we define an Image using Pixels:

```
class Image[T](nsize: Array[Int], ndata: Array[T]) {

    val size: Array[Int] = nsize
    val data: Array[T] = ndata

    def this(isize: Array[Int]) {
        this(isize, new Array[T](isize(0) * isize(1)))
    }

    def this(img: Image[T]) {
        this(img.size, new Array[T](img.size(0) * img.size(1)))
        for (i <- 0 until img.data.size) {
            data(i) = img.data(i)
        }
    }

}
```

(I think I should be able to do without the explicit declaration of size and data, and use just what has been named in the default constructor, but I haven't gotten that to work.)

Now I want to write code to use this, that doesn't have to know what type the pixels are. For example:

```
def idiv[T](a: Image[T], b: Image[T]) {
    for (i <- 0 until a.data.size) {
        a.data(i) = a.data(i).div(b.data(i))
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile:

```
(fragment of lindet-gen.scala):145:
error: value div is not a member of T
                 a.data(i) = a.data(i).div(b.data(i))
```

I was told in #scala that this worked for someone else, but that was on 2.8. I've tried to get 2.8-rc1 going, but the RC1 doesn't compile for me. Is there any way to get this to work in 2.7.7?

Comment: Not your question, but wouldn't a triple of Doubles be more appropriate than an array?

Comment: Yes, I should check that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `idiv` function has to know it'll actually be working with pixels.

```
def idiv[T <: Pixel[T]](a: Image[T], b: Image[T]) {
    for (i <- 0 until a.data.size) {
        a.data(i) = a.data(i).div(b.data(i))
    }
}
```

A plain type parameter `T` would define the function *for all possible types `T`*, which of course don't all support a `div` operation. So you'll have to put a generic constraint limiting the possible types to `Pixel`s.

(Note that you could put this constraint on the `Image` class as well, assuming that an image out of something different than pixels doesn't make sense)